# Replace Indented text using SED

Tags: regex, awk, sed, yaml

I am looking at replacing some indented lines in a Yaml file using sed.

```
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 500m
          memory: 512Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 250m
          memory: 256Mi
```

Yaml is strict about its indentation and will want to know how I can accomplish a replacement of the text after example "limits:"

I have tried `'0,/cpu:.*m/s//cpu: 900m/'` and `'/limits:/!b;n;s//ccpu: 900m'`

`'0,/cpu:.*m/s//cpu: 900m/'` outputs:

```
          resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 900m
          memory: 512Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 250m
          memory: 256Mi
```

The only issue I have with this is I will want to specify the replacement should be done on the example CPU for limits and not for the requests.

So I tried `'/limits:/!b;n;s//ccpu: 900m'` which outputs:

```
          resources:
        limits:
cpu: 900m
          memory: 512Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 250m
          memory: 256Mi
```

Notice how it is not properly indented? How can I achieve this by leaving the indentation as it is and also if I can specify 1st and 2nd lines after "limits:" or "requests:" that will be nice.

Comment: I'd suggest you want to parse YAML with a YAML processing tool such as [tag:yq]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot install [yaml parsing tools such as `yq`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yq), you can use this `gnu-sed` solution:

```bash
sed -E '/limits:/!b;n;s/^([[:blank:]]*cpu: ).*/\1900m/' file.yml

      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 900m
          memory: 512Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 250m
          memory: 256Mi
```

**Breakdown:**

- `/limits:/!b`: Search for text `limits:` otherwise branch to end of script
- `n`: Read/append the next line of input into the pattern space
- `s/.../.../`: Do this substitution

  - `^`: Match start
  - `([[:blank:]]*cpu: )`: Match 0 or more whitespaces followed by text `cpu:` . Capture this in capture group #1
  - `.*`: Match remaining text till end of line
  - `/\1900m/`: Replace with back-reference of capture group #1 i.e. `\1` followed by new value `900m`

Comment: Thank you so much for this! And thank you for the Breakup. Appreciate it Anubhava

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and in GNU `awk` you can try following `awk` code. Though tools which know yaml files are recommended in case they can't be used this will be helpful.

```bash
awk -v RS="^$" '
match($0,/(^|\n)([[:space:]]+resources:\n[[:space:]]+limits:\n[[:space:]]+cpu: )[^\n]+(\n.*)$/,arr){
  printf("%s",arr[1] arr[2] "900m" arr[3])
}
' Input_file
```

Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/f0S2vm/1) for used regex `(^|\n)([[:space:]]+resources:\n[[:space:]]+limits:\n[[:space:]]+cpu: )[^\n]+(\n.*)$` adding it here for better understanding for regex.

***Explanation:***

- `(^|\n)`: Creating 1st capturing group which matches either starting of value OR new line.
- `([[:space:]]+resources:\n[[:space:]]+limits:\n[[:space:]]+cpu: )`: Creating 2nd capturing group which matches spaces followed by resources followed by new line followed by spaces followed by limits: followed by new line followed by spaces cpu:
- `[^\n]+`: Matching everything before new line.
- `(\n.*)$`: Creating 3rd capturing group new lines followed by everything till end of line.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 'f{sub(/[^ ]+$/,"900m"); f=0} /limits:/{f=1} 1' file
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 900m
          memory: 512Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 250m
          memory: 256Mi
```